# I can’t get measures table to export in Power BI service

Tags: powerbi, export, measure

I have a table matrix visual on my report, and in this table I’ve added all of my measures. I then turned my rows into columns so that it all reads up and down. My problem is -  when I publish to PowerBI service and try to export this table to excel, It doesn’t give me any options. For example, I can hover over another table matrix that I have on my report and the ellipses will appear and then I can select Export. But for my table matrix with the measures, when I hover over it does not  give me the ellipses to select Export.

Is there a way around this? I need this table since the measures are all my KPIs and I have an ask to give the user the ability to export them to a excel sheet from PowerBI service.

I appreciate you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This could be one of two things.

1. Check "Header icons" is enabled for the visual. Select the visual,
   then on right pane go to Format > General > Header icons.
2. Header icons maybe hidden under another item on the report. Select the
   visual, then go to Format in the Ribbon and select Bring Forward/Bring to front.